# Sum two textfiles

Tags: python, loops, text-files

I need to go through 2 text files line by line and sum the lines, which then need to be returned in a third text file.

So if file1 was...

```
4
2
1
```

and file2 is...

```
3
2
1
```

file3 is...

```
7
4
2
```

I'm thinking I want to use a for loop to read through the first file and readline() to get the numbers from the second, but summing and writing the new file is getting me. Here's my not so brilliant approach thus far.

```
myfile = open(file1)
myfile2 = open(file2)
for line in file1:
    p = int(line) +  int(myfile2.readlines())
    f = open(newFile,"w")
    f.write(p)
file1.close()
file2.close()
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
f = open(file1)
b = open(file2)
sum_list = []
list1 = []
list2 = []
for i in f:
   list1.append(int(i))

for i in b:
    list2.append(int(i))

for i in range(len(list1)):
     sum_list.append(list1[i]+list2[i])

a = open(file3, 'w')

for i in sum_list:
     a.write(str(i))
     a.write('\n')
```

This program is slightly longer, but illustrates the way to solve the problem without zip().

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the two files separately, then convert the elements from string to `int` using the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and then using the `map` sum them as:

```
with open("file1.txt", "r") as f1, open("file2.txt", "r") as f2, open("file3.txt", "w") as f_out:
    num_sum = map(sum, zip(map(int, f1.readlines()), map(int, f2.readlines())))
    f_out.write("\n".join(map(str, num_sum)))
```

Comment: great answer. Would be even better if you unpacked the parts of it a little. (ie, explain how the `map` is constructed)

Answer (score 0):

Using [`zip` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), you can iterate over two files at once and write in the third:

```
# 1. Open the two input file in readmode, the result file in write-mode
with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2, open(file3, 'w') as f3:
     # 2. Get each line of the two first line in a single op
     for line_f1, line_f2 in zip(f1, f2):
         # 3. Write the result in the third file
         f3.write(int(line_f1) + int(line_f2))
```